# Sfml: Sprite scale transformation animation

Tags: c++, animation, sprites, sfml, transformation

Is there any way to animate a transformation on sf::Sprite like setScale or setPosition?

ie: `sprite.setScale(0.5f,0.5f);`. I want the transition between normal and half scale be smooth.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use interpolation between the two values.

A simple form:

```
Vector2 goalScale = new Vector2(1,1);
Vector2 resultScale = sprite.getScale();

resultScale+= (goalScale - resultScale)/2; // increase division for stronger easing

sprite.setScale(resultScale);
```

Alternatively use a C++ tweener library.

Comment: Thanks Sidar! It works, but i'll search for tweener library!